# Why the image size in markdown changes after exporting to PDF by Typora

Tags: html, css, markdown

I'm writing documents with Markdown in Typora, but I found something strange.

I found that my image got bigger after exporting to PDF.
The code I use in Typora is like below (the contents have no meaning):

```
## 1

<img src=".\timg.jpg" alt="timg" style="zoom: 33%;" />

## 2

<div style="float:left;border:solid 1px 000;margin:2px;"><img src=".\timg.jpg"  width="375" ></div>
$$
\frac{1}{2}
$$
sfsdfsdfasfsadfasfasfsafsd

<div style="float:none;clear:both;">
```

What I saw in Typora, is like below (that's really what I want):

[result in Typora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4gWS.png)

But after exporting to PDF by Typora, I got something like this:

[result in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwZf6.png)

It seems like the pictures were enlarged, and in the second part the layout is completely different.

Can anybody tells me how to fix this problem? I want the layout in the second part in PDF be the same in Typora : picture in left and text/formula in right, or inverly. And how to avoid magnifying the images after exporting to PDF?

I've found a "solution", like exporting to HTML at first, then printing it to PDF. But in this way, the hyperlink will disappear (for example, the hyperlink of the catalogue). So I need a another way. Thanks in advance.